# Stop performing the animation in background thread and run loop

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uitableview, nsrunloop

I run my animations in a UITAbleViewCell. 
Each cell has its own animation and the cells are reusable.
I use `[mView performSelectorInBackground:@selector(layoutSubview) withObject:nil];`

There in the background thread I initiate the runLoop to perform tasks like this:

```
- (void)startAnimation 
{
    NSRunLoop *mLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval target:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    mRunLoop = YES;
    while (mRunLoop == YES && [mLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]]);
}
```

and stop it:

```
- (void)stopAnimation 
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [[NSThread currentThread] cancel];
    }

    mRunLoop = NO;
    self.animationTimer = nil;
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());   
}
```

I run into problems when I fast scroll through table, because on the first cell initiation I begin the animation, so the first runLoop call occures which performs a setNeedDisplay and all the methods from it. But before finishing the first runLoop cycle the cell disappears from the view and is already available for reuse. So I begin clearing it, while the cycle is still performing operations and here I meet situations like

> message sent to deallocated instance

So could you please give me some hints of how should I correctly stop performing the operations in that thread? I mean if I want to realese for example an object, which is performing some actions how to immediately stop'em?

Hope I gave enough info.
Thanks

**UPDATE:** No ideas at all?

Comment: Uh, except for a few cases, you shouldn't be sending messages to anything in UIKit from anywhere but the main thread. UITableViewCell is not thread safe.

Comment: Yeap I know, all the UIKit operations I perform in Main thread, but the animations, quartz animations (chart drawing) is don in background thread.

Comment: Oh right. Pardon my inability to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a completely different stab on it:

Get rid of the cell's timers and background threads altogether!

Animation is not something where `NSTimer` is a good fit in the first place and having multiple timers won't help much, either.

`UITableView` has a method [`visibleCells`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells) and a method [`indexPathsForVisibleRows`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForVisibleRows). I'd suggest to use a single [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031) — which *is* suited for animation, as it calls you back with the actual refresh rate of the display or a fraction thereof — in your tableview-controller and in the callback of that display-link iterate over the visible cells.

If you want to schedule the display-link on the run-loop of a secondary thread, feel free to do so, but I'd check if you can get away without extra threading first.

Some code:

```
@interface AnimatedTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CADisplayLink *cellAnimator;
- (void)__cellAnimatorFired:(CADisplayLink *)animator;

@end

@implementation AnimatedTableViewController

@synthesize cellAnimator = cellAnimator_;

- (void)setCellAnimator:(CADisplayLink *)animator
{
    if (animator == cellAnimator_)
        return;

    [cellAnimator_ invalidate];
    cellAnimator_ = animator;

    [cellAnimator_ addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSCommonRunLoopModes];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.cellAnimator = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(__cellAnimatorFired:)];
    ...
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.cellAnimator = nil;
    ...

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)__cellAnimatorFired:(CADisplayLink *)animator
{
     NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
     [visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITableViewCell *cell, NSUInteger unused, BOOL *stop){
         [cell setNeedsDisplay];
     }];
}

...

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

NSTimer has a `-cancel` method that stops the timer from firing. Calling it in `-prepareForReuse` (and, for that matter, in `-stopAnimation`) may help.

However, this code looks rather dangerous.  Nesting run loops like this is almost never a good idea—and moreover, as far as I can tell it's totally unnecessary.  If you let `-startAnimation` return, your animation timer will still get run on the main run loop.  And if you're doing it this way because there's some code after `-startAnimation` that you want to delay, you should restructure your code so this isn't needed.

(If you drop the runloop stuff in `-startAnimation`, don't stop the runloop in `-stopAnimation` either.)

Something like the approach danyowdee recommends would be even better, but at least get rid of this runloop stuff.  It's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method for your problem

`[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourTarget selector:aSelector object: anArgument];`

Comment: Documentation says: "Cancels perform requests previously registered with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:." I execute the selector using performSelectorInBackground

Comment: No it doesn't, as I said, it is not suitable for my case.

Comment: To my mind you should manage yourself the queue in which you send your animations. If you do so you'll be able to cancel them when UITableViewCell are reused

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to avoid that behavior is assigning the delegate that receives the cancel method in other class that won't be reused. For example, you can have a private array of instances that process all the cancel methods, each row mapped into an array element.

I recommend you the lazy tables example provided by Apple in Xcode documentation. It's a great example of how to load images asynchroniously in background with a table. I think that also it would be useful for you for the scrolling subjects (decelerating and paging).

Only one more consideration, i don't recommend messing up with several cfrunloopstop, test it hard!